# Spring JPA criteria builder greaterThan : Can I pass String value for comparing Number type in database

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am using Spring Data JPA criteria builder `greaterThan` API for doing a comparison.

The database field `rating` is of type `NUMBER(5,0)`. Entity class has a field `rating` which is of type `Integer`. And I am passing the value of type `String` for the comparison.

Even though I am not passing the `Integer` value for the comparison, still it is returning valid results. Please help me understand how this is possible.

Does it mean, I can pass the java `String` version of the database field to the greaterThan method when the actual data type of the field in the database is of a different type.

and my comparison block of code looks like this

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();

Root<Customer> root = cq.from(Customer.class);
//you can see here , value 20 I am passing as String
Predicate comparisonPredicate = cb.greaterThan(root.get("rating"), "20");

cq.where(comparisonPredicate );

cq.select(root);

TypedQuery<Customer> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
```

Comment: At some point in the process (either in Java or in the Oracle SQL engine), there will be an implicit cast that will attempt to convert the value from a String to a number. You can try it directly in Oracle using `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 1 < '2'` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae4cd8bb0c8bc77feb56b0876fb60fc7).

Comment: Thank you,Any documentation that points to this conversion if this is happening in Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is [not documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#greaterThan-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-).
Looking at [the openJPA source code for Expressions.GreaterThan](https://github.com/apache/openjpa/blob/cb258aee424374a79b9d4fd7728d5ee5eb2cdc17/openjpa-persistence/src/main/java/org/apache/openjpa/persistence/criteria/Expressions.java#L920), and more specifically the toKernelExpression,

```java
@Override
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.exps.Expression toKernelExpression(ExpressionFactory factory, CriteriaQueryImpl<?> q){
  Value val1 = Expressions.toValue(e1, factory, q);
  Value val2 = Expressions.toValue(e2, factory, q);
  Expressions.setImplicitTypes(val1, val2, e1.getJavaType(), q);
  return factory.greaterThan(val1, val2);
}
```

JPA uses the type of the first expression to build the query.
This behavior looks to be an *accidental feature* more than an intentional implementation. You should **not** rely on this and should explicitly cast the variable. You could also use a [MetaModel](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-criteria-metamodel/) to get a compiler error when trying to compare apples to oranges.